# PHP how to freeze random number through form submission

Tags: php

I would like a program to generate a random number, to print out that number, and to maintain the same number when a user inputs a form field.

Right now, the following code always refreshes the random number generation.

I don't know what surrounding code might hold the initial value so that it does not change.

```
$x = rand(5,50);

echo $x."<br><br>";

echo "Enter the number you see above:";

function form1 () {
    function test_input_1($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    ?>

    <form id="question1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user_input1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['user_input1'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['user_input1']); }?>"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="user_input1Submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
    </form>

    <?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if ($_POST['user_input1'] !="") {
            $user_input1 = test_input_1($_POST["user_input1"]);
            // more variables here, per line -- and add them to the ="" above.

            return $user_input1;
        }
    } 
}

form1();
```

Comment: You could store the value in a hidden input field or in a session variable. This is for a captcha sorta authentication, correct?

Comment: ... and, if that randoms is something like a captcha, then session storage is more appropriate place for them

Comment: Since when does PHP allow for nested functions?

Comment: @PHPglue - [always](https://eval.in/418504)

Comment: @PHPglue [Since the very beginning](https://3v4l.org/TVDOM) of the PHP advent!!

Comment: @PHPGlue, they are not really nested as all. Functions are declared at global scope. The 'nested' function do not have access to the 'outer' function variables.

Comment: simple `isset($_POST['user_input1']) ? $_POST['user_input1'] : $x;` echo in your input field, of course `$x` is outside the function, so make a function ( getRandom() for example ) to produce $x and then call `getRandom()` instead of `$x` etc  to resolve scope issues.

Answer (score 0):

Such as this ( as per my comment ).  Of course this is assuming `user_input1` is the field for the random number.

```
<?php
    function getRandom(){
        return rand(5,50);
    }
//function form1 () {
    function cleanInput($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    $x = getRandom();
    echo $x."<br><br>";
    echo "Enter the number you see above:";
?>

<form id="question1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_input1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_input1']) ? cleanInput($_POST['user_input1'] ) : ''; ?>"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="user_input1Submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>

<?php
    /*? what's this for - but I would change
     the first if in unneeded if isset($_POST['user_input1']))
     then obviously it should be request method
     in any case it returns to oblivion below here.
     besides shouldn't it be above the form, just as easy to call in the form echo $_POST part, no?
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if ($_POST['user_input1'] !="") {
            $user_input1 = test_input_1($_POST["user_input1"]);
            // more variables here, per line -- and add them to the ="" above.

            return $user_input1;
        }
    } 
}
form1(); <-- oblivion as it's not setting anything.
*/
?>
```

I would personally do away with `form1()` function myself as it makes it less readable and really is unnecessary in this example.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, HTTP is stateless protocol. Cookie and Session have been created to track the users ( or requests ). You have to use session in your code to freze the random number. I wrote a simple code and added to beginning of your example.

```
    <?php
session_start(); // start the session
if(isset($_SESSION['random'])) {
    $x = $_SESSION['random'];
} else {
    $x = rand(5,50);
    $_SESSION['random'] = $x;
}



echo $x."<br><br>";

echo "Enter the number you see above:";

function form1 () {
    function test_input_1($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    ?>

    <form id="question1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user_input1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['user_input1'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['user_input1']); }?>"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="user_input1Submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
    </form>

    <?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        if ($_POST['user_input1'] !="") {

            $user_input1 = test_input_1($_POST["user_input1"]);
            // more variables here, per line -- and add them to the ="" above.
            return $user_input1;
        }
    } 
}

form1();
```

Comment: solution perfectly matched my given code (which is a proxy-abbreviation for the longer code -- and your solution matches the longer code)....  AND very succinctly and very well explained.  Thank you!  I just started on stackoverflow, so my vote won't show up until I have more points.

Comment: The freeze is so solid that I can exit from my browser window, exit from my browser, and restart my computer -- and the browser still remembers the frozen values.  I would like them to be able to change from one browser session to another, or even upon refresh.